Collection functions return not a function after working once
I have a project that uses Vue components and collection design pattern for list manipulation. Inside of the collection, I have an arr.add function that adds a new object to the list when a button is pressed. This works correctly the first time called but then shows an error stating it is not a function if it is called a second time. This is happening for all my function calls.
If I manually enter the data into the list and avoid using the collection call it works fine but if I use the collection for a second time I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: this.exerciseList.add is not a function
This is the collection model:
function ExerciseCollection(arr = []){

    arr.add = function (exercise, date){
        if (date){
            exercise.date = date;
        }
        exercise.id = genId(date);
        this.push(exercise);
        return this;
    }

    arr.delete = function (exercise){
        this.splice(this.indexOf(exercise), 1);
        return this;
    }

    arr.deleteSet = function (exercise, set){
        let editExercise = this.indexOf(exercise);
        editExercise.weight.splice(set, 1);
        editExercise.reps.splice(set, 1);
        editExercise.sets--;
        return this;
    }

    arr.addSet = function (exercise){
        this.indexOf(exercise).sets++;
        return this;
    }
    return arr;
}

This is where they are called:
const app = Vue.createApp({
    // All data for the app, must return an object
    data() {
        return {
            exerciseList: new ExerciseCollection().add({
                id: 0, title: 'Bench Press', date: '2024-04-03',
                sets: 2, reps: [10, 10], weight: [185, 185]
            }),
            dayList: new DayExerciseCollection(),
            reviewList: new ReviewCollection(),
            daysReview:{},
            selectedEditExercise: {},
            currentDay: ''
        };
    },
    methods: {
        
        addExercise(exercise, date){
            this.exerciseList.add(exercise, date);
            this.dayList.add(exercise, date);
        },
...(rest of the file works properly but is pretty long wont put it in here)


What does console.log(this.exerciseList.add) show when you get this error?

If that shows undefined, what does console.log(this.exerciseList) show?

It's a not a good idea to add custom methods to an array, nothing requires that.
The problem here is that Vue reactivity makes an arrays reactive in data and discards custom methods because they aren't expected. Vue 3 supports reactive classes with several known pitfalls but these are ES6 classes with prototype methods that won't cause problems.
It can even support method chaining but arr state needs to be a field and not an instance itself:
class ExerciseCollection {
  constructor(arr = []) {
    this.list = arr;
  }

  add(exercise, date){
    ...
    return this;
  }
}

